# How do I revoke all permissions for a selected table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I tried following command to remove all permissions of a user for a specific table:

```
REVOKE all ON db.tb1 FROM 'user2'@'localhost';
```

but I got this error:

```
ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user2' on host 'localhost' on table 'tb1'
```

even if it already has all privileges for whole database.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for user2 @localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------+
| Grants for user2@localhost                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*DC52755F3C09F5923046BD42AFA76BD1D80DF2E9' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* TO 'user2'@'localhost'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Grants don't include a negative grant structure to be recorded.

option 1) Move `db.tb1` to its own database

option 2) give user2 and explicit whitelist of tables in db that they are allowed to access.